# Внутри функции не срабатывает условие else if

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
    Внутри функции не срабатывают условия else if.
```

Неважно какой пункт выпадающего списка я выбираю,
у переменной num1 всегда будет значение 1000,
сработает только первое условие if,
else if не работают. Помогите понять в чём ошибка

```
  <div class="spisok1" >
          <select id="spisok11" onchange="calculated(this);">  
        <option value="opt1">Выберите пункт</option>
           <option value="opt2">Первый</option>
           <option value="opt3">Второй</option>
           <option value="opt4">Третий</option>
           </select>
           </div>


     function calculated(select){
         
let tip = select.options[select.selectedIndex];
      alert(tip.value);

         let num1 = tip;
         
         

if(num1 = "opt1" ){
  num1 = 1000;   


} else if (num1 = "opt3") {
num1 = 2000;    
} else if(num1 = "opt4") {
num1 = 3000;
}
         console.log(num1);
```

Comment: Сравнение в if' ах надо делать. У вас - присваивание

Answer (score 1):

Во первых `if (num1 = "opt1")` это не сравнение, замените на `if (num1 === "opt1")`.

Вы записываете в переменную `num1` значение `tip`. В первом блоке `if` вы получаете `true` (num1 === "opt1" и перезаписываете переменную `num1`, теперь `num1 === 1000`.
Cоответственно при сравнении `num1 === "opt3"` и `num1 === "opt4"` вы получаете `false`, так как:
`1000 !== "opt3"` и `1000 !== "opt4"`.

[if...else MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else)

```js
let tip = select.options[select.selectedIndex];

let num1 = tip; // num1 = "opt1"

if (num1 === "opt1") { // "opt1" === "opt1" => true
  num1 = 1000;
} else if (num1 === "opt3") { // 1000 === "opt3" => false
  num1 = 2000;
} else if (num1 === "opt4") { // 1000 === "opt4" => false
  num1 = 3000;
}
```